# evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNCWebView.isFileUploadSupported'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview, expo

I'm trying to get WebView to work for an Expo app on an Android phone. I ran "npx expo install react-native-webview" beforehand. When I run "expo start --dev-client" and then scan the QR code using the Expo app on the phone, I see some errors. Please help and thank you!

Code (from App.js):

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <WebView source={{ uri: 'put URL here' }}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Errors:

```
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNCWebView.isFileUploadSupported')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:203:40 in guardedLoadModule
```

Comment: Did you find a way around this, experiencing the same.